# PHP - Get variable from foreach into array for e-mail function?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

Apologies for the following question, as my PHP knowledge isn't hugely strong, But having google'd around, i can't seem to find a solution, or an explanation as to how i could complete this

I have a custom function in Wordpress with WooCommerce which fires off on order complete.

The idea is each item has a custom field for supplier, and a suppliers e-mail address, upon a completed order, we'd like to send an e-mail to that supplier requesting they ship those items direct to the customer.

Below is my code currently

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();
$address = $order->get_formatted_shipping_address();
$totalprice;
$str = "";
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $supplier = get_post_meta( $item['product_id'], 'Supplier', true );
        $supplier_email = get_post_meta( $item['product_id'], 'Supplier_Email', true );
        $str .= $product_name = $item['name']."  ";
        $str .= $product_id = $item['product_id']." ";
        $pprice = $item['price'];
        $name = $item['name'];
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $to = array("$supplier <$supplier_email>");
        $subject = "Please dispatch" + $name;
        $content = "Please send the following item \n".$str;
        $status = wp_mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers);
    }
```

Which works, however, if we have say 4 items, with 1 item being some 'supplier X' and 3 items being from 'supplier Y' we're sending out 3 individual e-mails to supplier X, As opposed to one e-mail, which lists all items.

I'm thinking that i need to get each $supplier_email from this foreach, into it's own array - and then send an e-mail that way? But i can't seem to get it to work thus far, Could anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: It's all a little bit blurry but maybe it's an idea to add the Supplier ID to an array in your foreach. Then check at the beginning if the current Supplier ID isn't already in the array.

Comment: Just do a loop through the items of the specific order first, and create an extra array that stores the supplier id as the key of the array and inside it an array with all the items. Then you can loop that array and nicely send the email to each supplier with one email and with all its items inside it.

Comment: Basically same what Bart mentioned :) only the ID check isnt needed. You can simply do like: `$array[$suplier_id]['items][] = array()`

Comment: Thanks for the info guys, could you give me any more info as to how i would actually get each supplier into the array? I'm currently trying to get each supplier into an array using

     $sps[] = array(get_post_meta( $items['product_id'], 'Supplier', true ));

But don't seem to be having much luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();
$suppliers = array();
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $supplier = get_post_meta( $item['product_id'], 'Supplier', true );
    $to = "$supplier <$supplier_email>";
    $suppliers[$supplier]['email'] = $to;
    $suppliers[$supplier]['items'][] = array('name'=>$item['name']);
}
```

You know the rest :)
Also note that i used supplier name, if you can try to get the ID instead this will make sure it is unique, in case 2 different supplier with same name occur.

For instance use:

`$supplier = get_post_meta( $item['product_id'], 'Supplier_ID', true );`

Comment: Amazing, thanks Rens!

So i guess we need to initiate the array outside of the loop, and i can see how we're adding the array into the new variable at the bottom, i have a few quick questions...

ideally i'd like to have the item name/price etc in the array, so i'm guessing the following would be what i need

`$suppliers[$supplier]['items'][] = array('name'=>$item['name'], 'price'=>$item['price'], 'SKU'=>$product_id, );`

Then would i need to run another loop on each supplier to send out the email? would that be something along the lines of

`foreach ($supplier as $sp) {
// code here
}`

Comment: Yep exactly like that, this wil only send one email to each supplier but with all their items :) So you only have 3 loops, one to loop orders and create supplier array with their items, one to loop the suppliers, and inside that a loop to get the items.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info Rens! This now works perfectly.

For anyone reading this post, who'd need it for future reference, here's the code i've ended up with:

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$address = $order->get_formatted_shipping_address();
$ordernum = $order->get_order_number();
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $suppliers = array();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $supplier_email = get_post_meta( $item['product_id'], 'Supplier_Email', true );
        $supplier = get_post_meta( $item['product_id'], 'Supplier', true );
        $to = "$supplier <$supplier_email>";
        $suppliers[$supplier]['email'] = $to;
        $suppliers[$supplier]['items'][] = array('name'=>$item['name'], 'price'=>$item['price'], 'SKU'=>$item['product_id'], 'Quantity'=>$item['qty'], 'Price'=>$item['line_total'], 'VAT'=>$item['line_tax'] );
    }
    foreach ($suppliers as $sp) {

       $content = '<b>Please supply the following items:</b><br>';

        foreach($sp['items'] as $item) {
            $content .= $item['name'] . ' - SKU:' . $item['SKU']. ' - &pound;' . number_format($item['Price'], 2) .' (quantity of ' . $item['Quantity'] . ')' . "<br>\r\n";
        }
        $content .= "<br><br><b>Shipping Address:</b><br>";
        $content .=  $address;
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $subject = 'Order #' . $ordernum . '- Please dispatch the following items:';
        $status = wp_mail($sp, $subject, $content, $headers);

    }
```

Comment: Hey, looks nice, small note, I don't know if you would want to use ISO-8859-1 for your email charset. "UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding that can represent any unicode character. ISO-8859-1 is a single byte encoding that can represent the first 256 unicode characters. Although both encode ASCII exactly the same way." I personally always us UTF-8, I had problems with ISO when some customers with foreign languages used a plugin I build.